# Sort a query using view counter

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I want to make a projection that sort some pages depending on the user view count.
So i have installed the voting module and then the content view counter module.I 've enabled the later and i 've managed to display the view counter  in every page.But when i m trying to make a query that sorts based on the number of view counts there isn't such a parameter in query list.
So how can i sort a query based on the number of view counts?Is there any way to make view counts sortable?

P.S My first thought is to add a new field to my pages with the value of the  view counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to sort a query by TotalViews we have to modify some code parts inside the  content view counter module.

1)Modify the Models

```
public class UserViewRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
    public virtual int TotalViews { get; set; }
}

public class UserViewPart : ContentPart<UserViewRecord>
{
    [Required]
    public int TotalViews
    {
        get { return Record.TotalViews; }
        set { Record.TotalViews = value; }
    }
}
```

Actually we create a table when we can store the total views.So we have to follow 2 more steps

2)Add some code to migration.cs

```
public int UpdateFrom2() {

        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("UserViewRecord", table => table
          .ContentPartRecord()
          .Column("TotalViews", DbType.Int32)
      );

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(
            typeof(UserViewPart).Name, cfg => cfg.Attachable());

        return 3;
    }
```

3)Modify our handler class to specify that an IRepository of UserViewRecord should be used as the storage for this part.

```
 public UserViewPartHandler(IVotingService votingService,
        IOrchardServices orchardServices, IRepository<UserViewRecord> repository)
    {
        _votingService = votingService;
        _orchardServices = orchardServices;
        Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository)); 
        //more code
        //more code

     }
```

After all, as Bertrand Le Roy said, we can add a binding for the TotalViews property and use TotalViews as a sorting criterion.

Answer (score 1):

Under Queries, click on the Bindings tab, then add a binding for the voting counter. Once that is done, you should be able to add the counter as a sorting criterion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.However the query did not return any results(maybe i m not using properly the voting widget?) As i can see from shape tracing the property i want to use is TotalViews from the User View part (that comes from content view counter module) i.e @Model.ContentItem.Parts[11].TotalViews

Comment: Do you mean the query doesn't return any results whether you attempt to sort or not?

Comment: The query does not return any results when i add the voting counter as a sorting criterion.If i dont use sorting it returns the expected results

Comment: Do the types for those results actually have the voting part?

Comment: The content type that i want to sort has the user view part (this is from the content view counter module that depends on voting).There is no option for a "direct" voting part.

Comment: Then you can't query on it unless you build your own sorting provider.

Comment: Thank you again for your help.Finally i 've managed to find a solution.Maybe it is not the best one but it works.I ll write it down as an answer.If any remarks,you are welcome :)